# django-autocomplete-light, not load selected value

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I use in form Select2Multiple:

```
events = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('vispage', 'Visited Page'), ('visevent', 'Visited Event'), required=False, widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-placeholder': 'Select type(s)'}))
```

template:

```
<div class="form-group">{{ form.events }}</div>
{% if form.events.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ form.events.errors }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

but give error, regardless choose I any values in the form or not::

> Select a valid choice.  is not one of the available choices.

Comment: Can you show your template?

Comment: And the code in your view?

Comment: in view: if form.is_valid(): some_code, but form is not valid

Comment: Add a `print` statement before you call `is_valid` and look at the form in the console. You might be able to get a better idea from that.

Comment: I look through print and determine mistake, when I do choice one value, in form added two value and one of them empty <option value=""></option> (first value) and apparently empty values are not allowed, although I have "required = False". How can I allowed empty values?

Comment: that is first empty value <option value="" selected></option> I have always selected, regardless, did I choice value in form or not

Comment: Perhaps add a default value?

Comment: yes, perhaps need to add the default value